# Grouping asynchronous messages

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, locking, race-condition

I have a use case where customers' actions are being published in a queue. Consumers process these messages and update customers' statistics based on their actions. Example:

Messages:

- customer 1 -> action
- customer 3 -> action
- customer 1 -> action
- customer 2 -> action
- customer 2 -> action

Consumers process these messages as follows:

1. Take an action.
2. Calculate the statistics delta based on the action.
3. Get current customer's statistics
4. Apply delta and update the customer's statistics.

The problem is that this is a high-throughput place, therefore race conditions sometimes happen. Imagine having 5 consumers for the queue, which means that the actions of customers 1 and 2 will be processed in parallel, therefore between steps 3 and 4, consumers can get the same statistics and conflict to write the new data.

To resolve this issue, I implemented locks - consumers take a batch of messages and acquire a lock based on `customer_id` making other consumers wait if they get messages with the same `customer_id`.

Now the problem is, when the first consumer takes a batch of messages and acquires the lock, sometimes it makes the rest of the consumers just hang and wait, which is not ideal because it makes scaling tricky - basically, the queue is being processed by only one consumer. I'm struggling to come up with a solution to somehow group the messages so separate consumers can process separate batches related to certain `customer_id` and not lock each other. Is there any best practices for such a use case?